# How to synchronize 2 different tables in 2 different databases in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have one website with XY features, having 50000 users, in a database where Members table has 35 columns for members different info.

Now, I would like to attach a webshop that has a different set of columns in its member table, this webshop is empty so far.

I would need to attach/synchronize these two databases, so the 50000 users from site one, could log in on site two. Also if they register on one site, they should be added to site two automatically.

Both websites need only username, email and password, for registration.

What would be the best approach to get 2 different tables synced on 3 columns  that have different column names?

Comment: is it possible for you to extract user table in separate database and use this database as common authentication database for two site.

Comment: or You can create VIEW representing your common USERS table in each database.